# Unbootable Windows 7 Enterprise partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, mbr

Can my partition with Windows 7 Enterprise become bootable again after making it "active" in my Windows 8 Customer Preview Partition.

The errormessage I get when trying to boot it is: 
Remove disks or other media.

The error came after I did the following
- I shrinked the my Windows 7 partition
- Installed Windows 8 CP on the new free space
- I marked my Windows 7 installation / partition as Active in the disk management
- Rebooted, and got the message?

Can I some how recreate the Boot record or something to make the installation bootable once again?

Answer (score 3):

Boot to your Windows 7 Install Disk. It's got a recovery mode that should be able to see the mismatch in partition markings, and fix such. However, be warned this may break Windows 8. It all kinda depends on how you installed it, I guess.

Also, you should consider running [Windows 8 in a VM](http://www.file-extensions.org/article/guide-install-windows-8-as-a-virtual-machine-with-vmware) so that when strange stuff happens, you don't have a broken workstation, only a broken virtual machine.

Comment: +1 I have used this technique several times recently with great success.  It was always quick and painless.  Boot to the DVD, select the language, then at the install screen select repair instead of install.  Also, good advice on the VM.

Comment: Or, instead of a VM, since you have Windows 7 as the first OS, you can boot from VHD, which is a lot cooler and cleaner and lets you do native hardware access (e. g. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx)

Comment: Oooh, fancy. :)